# Pervasive Stored Proceedure with variable

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, pervasive

I want to run this code from my query windows inside Excel but I get an error after it completes the first statement. If can run it fine in PCC. I'm assuming I need to create a stored procedure with a variable. Parent = 'B-8579-K' is the variable value.

1. How to I create the stored procedure?
2. How do I call the stored procedure and pass on the variable?
3. Will the call even work from within Excel without causing an error?

   ```
   delete z_Expl_BOM_Temp; 

   insert into z_Expl_BOM_Temp 
       select 
           Parent, L1_Child_Seq, L1_Child, L1_Child_QTY, 
           L2_Child_Seq, L2_Child, L2_Child_QTY, 
           L3_Child_Seq, L3_Child, L3_Child_QTY, 
           L4_Child_Seq, L4_Child, L4_Child_QTY, 
           L5_Child_Seq, L5_Child, L5_Child_QTY
       from 
           EGC_Expl_BOM_TT 
       where 
           Parent = 'B-8579-K' ;
   ```

Comment: `delete from z_Expl_BOM_Temp;` ?

Comment: What's the error?  WHat version of PSQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the SP created without an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EGC_Expl_BOM_TT(in :CParent varchar(20));

BEGIN

delete from z_Expl_BOM_Temp; 

insert into z_Expl_BOM_Temp 
    select 
        Parent, L1_Child_Seq, L1_Child, L1_Child_QTY, 
        L2_Child_Seq, L2_Child, L2_Child_QTY, 
        L3_Child_Seq, L3_Child, L3_Child_QTY, 
        L4_Child_Seq, L4_Child, L4_Child_QTY, 
        L5_Child_Seq, L5_Child, L5_Child_QTY
    from 
        EGC_Exploded_BOM 
    where 
    Parent = :CParent;

END;
```

I can call is just fine in PCC.  However, when I run the CALL in Excel's query window is will execute the procedure but when it completes I get this error:

"The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened.
Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganized, then try the operation again."

This might now be turning into a VBA question.  Can I run the CALL with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Creating Stored Procedures in Pervasive are documented [here](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/syntaxref.02.24.html).
An example of a stored procedure that takes a parameter is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Checkmax(in :classid integer);
BEGIN
DECLARE :numenrolled integer;
DECLARE :maxenrolled integer;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :numenrolled FROM Enrolls WHERE class_ID = :classid;
SELECT Max_size INTO :maxenrolled FROM Class WHERE id = :classid;
IF (:numenrolled >= :maxenrolled) THEN
PRINT 'Enrollment Failed. Number of students enrolled reached maximum allowed for this class' ;
ELSE
PRINT 'Enrollment Possible. Number of students enrolled has not reached maximum allowed for this class';
END IF;
END;
```

And then calling it:

```
CALL Checkmax(101)
```